# Determine whether the sequence of functions converge uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

(1) $f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n(x)= \arctan(nx)$, $X=[0,\pi]$. 
(2) $f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n(x)= x^ne^{-xn}$, $X=(0,\infty)$.

For (2), I divided the situation into three cases, where $x \in (0,1)$,  and $x \in (1,\infty)$, and $x=1$. For the first case, it is easy to check the limit is $0$, since $\frac{x}{e^x} \leq 1$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{x}{e^x})^n = 0$. For the second case, the same limit is in the form of $\infty \cdot 0$, so I used the usual trick and used L'Hospital $n$ times to get the limit is $0$. For the last case, also the limit $0$. Thus, it converges uniformly to the function constantly $0$. Are these enough, or should I check something else? Moreover, are my limit calculations correct, I am not that good at calculating stuff?

For (1), I am not good at trigonometric functions and their limits, so I could not do anything about it. Can you help me with that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For (1), each $f_n$ is continuous. What do you know about the uniform limit of continuous functions? Check to see if the pointwise limit does this.

Comment: @Liam I know that the limit must also be continuous. The problem is I do not know to calculate the pointwise limit of this function. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: that's the idea. $f_n(0) = \arctan(0) = 0$ for all $n$. On the other hand, if $x\neq 0$, $nx\to \infty$ and $\arctan(nx)\to \pi/2$. This shows that the pointwise limit isn't continuous.

Comment: Your argument for (2) shows that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise, but doesn't say anything about whether the convergence is uniform. To do this you need to show that $f_n(x)$ can be made arbitrarily small _for all $x$ at the same time_ if $n$ is beg enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) just note that $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n (x) \to \frac {\pi} 2$ for  $x >0$. So the limit function is not continuous and the  convergence cannot be uniform.

For 2) note that $f_n(x)=(\frac x {e^{x}})^{n} \to 0$ for  each $x$. Now consider the function $\frac  x {e^{x}}$ on $(0,\infty)$. Check (by differentiation ) that this function has its maximum value at $x=1$ so the function is positive and bounded by $\frac  1 e <1$. Hence $f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

(1) On $(0,\pi]$, the pointwise limit is $\arctan(n x)\to\pi/2$. 
You can show that this is not the pointwise limit at $0$ (indeed, $\arctan(n\cdot 0)=0$ for any value of $n$) so the pointwise limit of $f_n$ is the discontinuous function,
$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x=0\\\pi/2&x\in(0,\pi]\end{cases}$.

You should therefore be able to conclude that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$.

(2) You already showed that the pointwise limit is $0$. To show that the convergence is uniform, observe that 
$\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)=0$ implies that $nx^{n-1}e^{-nx}+(-n)x^ne^{-nx}=0\implies x=0,1$. Indeed these are the minima and maxima values of $f_n$ on $[0,\infty)$. So $f_n(x)$ is uniformly bounded by $f_n(1)=e^{-n}$ and thus uniformly convergent.

(It is not enough to say that the pointwise limit is continuous. For example, $f_n(x)=x/n$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is $0$, but observe that this function is not bounded and so the convergence is not uniform.)